# Turn lines in file into list of input

Tags: bash, arguments

The command i want to execute:

```
tool <input> [<input> ...] <output>
```

I have the input list in a file, separated by newline.

I want to put that file's content into the input field. What I have tried:

First I load the file into an array:

```
# Load file into array.
declare -a list
let i=0
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
    list[i]="${line_data}"
    ((++i))
done < file.txt
```

Then I tried using that array in the command as:

```
tool $list output
```

But it doesn't work as I expected. Can someone help me on this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there.

```
tool "${list[@]}" output
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. I will mark as answer when the timer is done :)